# No multilingual support cannot enable multilingual quotes on input line?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

i get an error in `\begin{equation}`, i write long equation and split it using `\\`. 
it shows an error

```
 Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable
 tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} into
 your preamble
```

Comment: This is a warning. Not an error. Just write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` after the loading of `pgfplots` in your preamble. You should consider updating your system as the current version is 1.12 I believe. Anyway, this has nothing to do with your equation. Note that you can not just split an equation by \\. You have to use a `split` or `align` or similar environment.

Comment: If you want to get any real help here, we will need an MWE which produces the problems you are facing.

Comment: Consider using `\multline` (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments)